# perl one liner in line edits with a bak file CSV

Tags: perl

I have a field where if the 11th field of a line in a csv file is larger than 6 characters,
the whole line needs to be removed.

```
casoer@casperbox::/here/s/johnny$ head /come/and/play/with/us/danny.csv
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,S,FOREVERRR,0,862,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,L,WONKY,13783,10196,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,L,WONKY,13783,10196,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,L,CRACK?g,221,188,
,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,L,CRACK?g,221,188,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,S,S,TRIP,4169,2858,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,S,S,TRIP,4169,2858,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,S,S,WRIDE,450,450,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,S,S,WRIDE,450,450,
D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,L,FOOHK,157,157,
```

this works great --

```
casoer@casperbox::/here/s/johnny$ perl -nle 'print unless /\,\w{7}\,/' /come/and/play/with/us/danny.csv > /come/and/play/with/us/danny.csv.trap
```

this will remove the line "D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,S,FOREVERRR,0,862,"

when I try and tidy this up -

```
casoer@casperbox::/here/s/johnny$ perl -p -i.bak -nle 'print unless /\,\w{7}\,/' /come/and/play/with/us/danny.csv
```

the .bak file is created - but the "D,642,0642,RED,RUM,,M,,L,S,FOREVERRR,0,862," is not removed from the in line file.
I would like to have the oneliner create a bak up file if we are going to have it do -i for inline editing.

Comment: I don't know why either should work. `\w{7}` doesn't match any line. `\w{7,}` would.

Answer (score 4):

To match on 7 *or more* characters, you would need to include a `,` after the 7.

Including `-p` causes perl to `print $_` in the `continue` phase of the loop, so you'll double up on unmatched lines.

However, to match *only* the 11th field, it's more appropriate to autosplit lines on ',' and test the length of the field:

`perl -i.bak -F, -anwe 'print unless length $F[10] > 6'`

Keep in mind this will only work as a one-liner if your CSV does not include quoted commas. If you need more you'll have to look into the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV) module.

Comment: That regex will match when *any* field is 7 characters or longer, not just the 11th field. `perl -i.bak -F, -anwe 'print unless length $F[10] > 6'` or similar would be better.

Comment: Ah yes, glossed over the bit about the 11th field. Updating the answer

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the `-p` switch, which overrides the `-n` switch, and produces output for every line of input.

I'll bet you are now seeing duplicate output for most of the lines in your input.